# Android onResume not called after onNewIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-broadcast, onresume

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which should launch activity:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (wakeLock == null)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ApplicationScreen.instance.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    }
    if (!wakeLock.isHeld())
    {
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    try
    {
            if (ApplicationScreen.instance != null) {
                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(context, MainScreen.class);
                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                ApplicationScreen.instance.startActivity(dialogIntent);
            } else {
                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(context, MainScreen.class);
                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                context.startActivity(dialogIntent);
            }

    } catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
    }
}
```

My `MainScreen` is:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    Log.e("TAG", "onResume");
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // getIntent() should always return the most recent
    setIntent(intent);
    Log.e("TAG", "onNewIntent");
}
```

`onResume` is never called after `onNewIntent`. I expect that, if device go to sleep, my `BroadcastReceiver` should wake it up and launch my `MainScreen`.
Also should tell, that `MainScreen` extends `ApplicationScreen`. And `ApplicationScreen` extends `Activity`.

> EDIT:

Device doesn't wake up. Screen stays off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only working solution for me is to use the decrepated `PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` when `onNewIntent()` is called.

```
int SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK = 10;   
PowerManager lPm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock lWl = lPm.newWakeLock(SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP);
lWl.acquire(1000);
```

This will trigger `onResume` if the Activity was stopped by pressing the power button. Then you should use the recommended `WindowManager` flags `FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON` and `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`.

Comment: I also can fix it by using deprecated PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK. But I hoped to find better solution without deprecated code. Looks like there is not such solution.

Answer (score 0):

`OnNewIntent()` always get called for `singleTop/Task` activities except for the first time when activity is created. At that time `onCreate` is called.

You can invoke `onNewIntent` always by putting it into `onCreate` method like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  //code
}
```

And, Your activity has already gone through its lifecycle to resume. If the act is resumed they could simply call `onNewIntent()` and stay in the resumed.

Comment: From documentation "An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so you can count on onResume() being called after this method.". Besides device is sleep, so onResume should be called anyway.

Comment: @MaximMetelskiy so you say that your device wakes up, screen switches on, your activity gets shown but still no onCreate/onStart/onResume being called?

Comment: @pskink I edit my question to clarify it. Device doesn't wake up. And It's part of problem.